# how to send a notification to android using fcm and j2ee

Tags: android, firebase, jakarta-ee, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to build an app to send a notification from j2ee web application to our client application android.

I find a lot of example but using google cloud messaging and not using FCM.

I would like an exemple to do this using a simple function in java.

This function permit to send a notification from my server to our mobile app installed in android device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can achieve it through FCM. I haven't used j2ee, but can give you some directions to do the job.

1. Configure your application to receive notifications from Firebase
   console. There is a lots of tutorial available and it's very easy.
2. Use a POST request to send the notification from your server to device. Here is the json part.

......

```
https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
Content-Type:application/json
Authorization:key=AIhhjGu76G...P0Gzu7B5aAnoYUd
{   
    "data": {
      "title": "notification_title",
      "body": "notification_body"
    },
    "to" : "jh578_gsh....jhHGFJ76FH"
}
```

Comment: hello sir,first step its ok but step 2 i dont know how i do this

Comment: you have any example using php

Comment: follow this link: https://github.com/miskoajkula/Fcm/blob/Fcm/php_scripts/push_notification.php

Comment: @MohamedElgarnaoui did u find any solution of how to send notification from java server or j2ee to android device?

Comment: @MohamedElgarnaoui then please do share your solution

Comment: @MohamedElgarnaoui dhruvamprashant@rediffmail.com

Comment: what do you mean by side android?? @MohamedElgarnaoui